# how to normalize an audio file so that the length (row) of the data is equal?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to do a comparison of 2 audio files (each audio file is speaking "ba a ta") with the existing function in matlab called Dynamic Time Warping (DTW). Before doing a dynamic time warping, I get an array/vector from the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) functions available in matlab, my code so far (my matlab filename: test.m):

```
fftRecording1 = fft(audioread('C:\Users\handy\Documents\MATLAB\my_recording_1.wav'));
fftRecording2 = fft(audioread('C:\Users\handy\Documents\MATLAB\fajar.wav'));
dist = dtw(fftRecording1, fftRecording2);
```

When I try the DTW function there is an error because the length (row) of the array/vector 2 file is different. Error message:

```
Error using dtw (line 82)
The number of rows between X and Y must be equal when X and Y are matrices

Error in test (line 3)
dist = dtw(fftRecording1, fftRecording2);
```

contents of the fftRecording1 and fftRecording2 variables
[image: variables fftRecording1 and fftRecording2]

[image: total row on fftRecording1]

[image: total row on fftRecording2]

My question is: before do the FFT and DTW, how do step by step normalize so that the length (row) 2 audio files is equal? or there are other ways to make the data length (row) 2 audio files is equal?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Time Warping does not need the input sequences to be of same length. DTW is actually used to find similarity between two different time aligned sequences.

Comment: In matlab, if we call the dtw function the length of the vector or array must be equal. This can be seen from the error. If as you mean, then how to call or write the dtw function in matlab?

Comment: @MohamadHandyNugraha see the link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping implementation is also present in this article.

Comment: No, they don’t need to have the same length in a time-related-sense. They need to have the same number of dimensions (2D Signal, 3D Signal,...) which is equivalent of their number or rows. The whole idea of DTW is to match similar contents which might be stretched to different lengths - so there would absolutely be no point in requiring the inputs to have the same length.

Comment: @Marcus yes, dimension of feature needs to be same. but number of features need not be same.

Comment: What do you mean by features? A signal is nothing else than a vector with each element of the vector belonging to a particular point in time. Let’s say you record temperature every second and you do that for 10 seconds in total. You’ll end up with a vector of 10 temperatures. With DTW you could now compare this 10-element vector against a second vector which you recorded over 30 seconds, so that it has 30 elements. If your signal contains temperature and humidity. Then the 1st vector grows to a matrix of 2 rows and 10 colums while your 2nd vector grows to 2x30, where the 2 is mandatory

Comment: @Marcus the dimension you call row, I am calling it feature.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`dtw`'s documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dtw.html):

> To stretch the inputs, dtw repeats each element of x and y as many times as necessary. If x and y are matrices, then dist stretches them by repeating their columns. In that case, x and y must have the same number of rows.

In your case your columns represent the audio channels, with the rows representing the quantity to be aligned (i.e. the reverse of what `dtw` is expecting). To setup the inputs according to what `dtw` expect, simply transpose the inputs:

```
dist = dtw(transpose(fftRecording1), transpose(fftRecording2));
```

Comment: Note that you might alternatively be able to zero pad both audio sequences to an equal length (the maximum length of the 2 audio files), and the resulting frequency bins after the FFT will be aligned (removing the need for `dwt` altogether).

Comment: I still got the error of this code: `dist = dtw(transpose(fftRecording1), transpose(fftRecording2));`. Error message: `Error in dtw (line 98)
  C = unconstrainedCumulativeDistance(x, y, metric);

Error in test (line 3)
dist = dtw(transpose(fftRecording1), transpose(fftRecording2));` does it require zero padding before FFT?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to pad when using `dtw`

Answer (score 1):

No, they don’t need to have the same length in a time-related-sense. They need to have the same number of dimensions (2D Signal, 3D Signal,...) which is equivalent to their number or rows. The whole idea of DTW is to match similar contents which might be stretched to different lengths - so there would absolutely be no point in requiring the inputs to have the same length.

Related to your question: just call the dtw with the transposed of your signals and you will get a proper result.

```
dtw(signal1’, signal2’);
```

You should apply the DTW on the original signals rather than the fourier transforms. The FFT transfers the signal from time to frequency domain. So instead of warping signal1 in order to match signal2, you are warping frequencies when using FFT before DTW. The amplitude of the fourier transform depends on the number of points in the considered FFT-Time-Window. From my point of view there is absolutely no point in applying DTW on a fourier transform.

Comment: `fft1'` is not the transpose of the signal but the complex conjugate transpose, an important difference for complex signals such as that computed by `fft`.

Comment: Do you agree that a complex conjugate is a signal on its own? DTW takes two signals and compares them. The author wants to compare the two complex conjugates of two original signals. Thus, the complex conjugates take the rolls of the signals the DTW is expecting.

Comment: I agree that DWT can align complex conjugate signals just like it can align the original signals. But the OP wants to compare the original signals, and if the intention is to extract phase information working with the complex conjugates can introduce confusion, hence my warning.